# Resetting logical Direct-Access Error || RHEL 7.x

Tags: linux, redhat, hp, raid10, scsi

We have an error for the LVM resetting device which has been impacting our Linux server during this period.

kernel: hpsa 0000:02:00.0: scsi 0:1:0:1: resetting logical  Direct-Access     HP       LOGICAL
VOLUME   RAID-1(+0) SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=1

kernel: hpsa 0000:02:00.0: device is ready.
Below current SCSI disks.

```
[0:0:0:0]    storage HP       P420i            6.68  -
[0:1:0:0]    disk    HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   6.68  /dev/sda
[0:1:0:1]    disk    HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   6.68  /dev/sdb
[1:0:0:0]    tape    HP       Ultrium 4-SCSI   U57D  /dev/st0
[2:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  hp       DVD A  DU8D4SH   MHE4  /dev/sr0
```

Also by checking the disks, we didn't find any HW failure.

```
Smart Array P420i in Slot 0 (Embedded)

Note: Predictive Spare Activation Mode is enabled, physical drives that are in predictive failure state will not be available for use as data or spare drives.

(sn: 00143803620FFA0)

Port Name: 1I

Port Name: 2I

Internal Drive Cage at Port 1I, Box 1, OK

Internal Drive Cage at Port 2I, Box 1, OK array A (SAS, Unused Space: 0 MB)

  logicaldrive 1 (279.4 GB, RAID 1, OK)

  physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 300 GB, OK, spare)
array B (SAS, Unused Space: 0 MB)

  logicaldrive 2 (558.7 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)

  physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:5 (port 2I:box 1:bay 5, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:6 (port 2I:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:7 (port 2I:box 1:bay 7, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:8 (port 2I:box 1:bay 8, SAS, 300 GB, OK, spare)
SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model SRCv8x6G) 380 (WWID: 500143803620FFAF)
```

This error was found only on one of the servers while others not suffering from the same problem.

I am trying to find a way to detect the problem fix as all topics going to a hw faulty while I didn't find any HP HW failures